# Why does an autorelease pool error occur when askinteger is called from a tkinter menu in Python 3.6?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6, simpledialog

I would like to call askinteger() from a tkinter menu in Python 3.6.3.  When I do this, the dialog box appears and I can enter an answer, but when I close the dialog box I get an autorelease pool error and the script exits.  When I call the same method from a button, it works fine.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import askinteger

def age_input():
    age_input = askinteger("Pop up", "Enter age")
    print(age_input if age_input != "" else "<empty>")

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("300x200")

menubar = tk.Menu(win)
dropDown = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
dropDown.add_command(label = "Get Age", command = age_input)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "Drop Down", menu = dropDown)
win.config(menu = menubar)

button = tk.Button(win, text="Get Age", command = age_input).pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Here is the error.

```
objc[15253]: Invalid or prematurely-freed autorelease pool 0x7fe0de82f050.
Abort trap: 6
```

Note that when I run the script with Python 2.7 (with suitable changes to the tkinter names), askinteger runs correctly when called from both the menu and the button.

I am using Mac OS X 10.13.3

Comment: The code snippet works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 running Python3.6. Perhaps your Tk install is an old version?